# What is the difference between these two Nginx regex patterns?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

What is the difference between the following two Nginx regex patterns?

```
location ~* /v1/path1/(.*)/path3
```

and

```
location ~* /v1/path1/(.*?)/path3
```

The difference is the `?` in the regex.

All I intend to do is match all paths in `/v1/path1/*/path3`. I tested both and they both seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greediness of the capture. Both regular expressions will match the same strings, but the capture may be different in each case.

For example, the string `/foo/v1/path1/bar/path3/path3` will match both locations.

In the first case, `$1` equals `bar/path3` because the capture is greedy and absorbs the first "path3" because there is another that satisfies the regular expression.

In the second case, `$1` equals `bar` because the capture is not greedy and absorbs the minimum amount to text to satisfy the regular expression.